# C++ == operator overloading (impementations)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have these prototypes declared in ULong.h

```
  bool operator== (const ULong& ) const;
  bool operator== (unsigned long long) const;
  friend bool operator== (unsigned long long, const ULong&);
```

In ULong.cpp, I'm trying to implement them:

```
bool ULong::operator== (const ULong& ul) const
{
    if(_num_digits != ul._num_digits)
        return false;
    for(unsigned i = 0;i < _num_digits; i++)
    {
        if(_number[i] != ul._number[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool ULong::operator== (unsigned long long l) const
{
    return *this == ULong(l);
}

ULong operator== (unsigned long long l, const ULong& ul)
{
    return ULong(l) == ul;
}
```

And I get compiler error:

> ULong.cpp:358:56: error: new declaration ‘ULong operator==(long long
> unsigned int, const ULong&)’
> In file included from ULong.cpp:10:0:
>
> ULong.h:76:15: error: ambiguates old declaration ‘bool operator==(long long unsigned int, const ULong&)’

I can't understand how to implement this method properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration says it returns a `bool`. The definition says it returns an `ULong` for some reason. That's your error, as the compiler told you already. Why did you switch the return type in the definition?

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration returns a `bool` but your implementation returns a `ULong` !

Comment: @JacobVoronin, yes I missed the `friend` keyword, your problem is the returned type.

Answer (score 2):

The return type is the problem. In the definition its ULong and it should be bool. ;)